# My href link buttons don't work online

Tags: javascript, css, html, href

I've just creted my first website in HTML5 and javascript and all the links work offline (double and triplechecked it), but when I uploaded it onto the host server, none of the links work. Could anyone give me any suggestions? Here's and example of my link buttons:

```
<div>
<center>
<button style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;height:25px;width:100px;font-size:14px"><a href="hoverB.html">Books</a></button>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: have you put the all the files in your root folder??

Comment: Hi, yes I did, everything is there

Comment: Define "don't work".  What happens?

Comment: Use the Fiddler tool to see the actual request to the server, and the response.

Comment: POssible the URL just doesn't point to the right place once on the server. Post your structure and a bit more code.

Answer (score 3):

You put an anchor tag inside a button. I assumed that you want to redirect the user if they click on the button. You can do something like this:

Example 1:

```
<a href="page.html"><button type="button">Click on me</button></a>
```

Example 2: (Recommended)

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='page.html'">Click on me</button>
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Or else you can also add anchor tag with css that makes it look like a button

```
<a href="page.html" class="btn">Click on me</a>

.btn:active {
      position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    color: #fcd3a5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f47a20), to(#faa51a));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f47a20, #faa51a);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f47a20', endColorstr='#faa51a');
}

.btn{
         display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0 2px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        color: #fef4e9;
    border: solid 1px #da7c0c;
    background: #f78d1d;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#faa51a), to(#f47a20));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #faa51a, #f47a20);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#faa51a', endColorstr='#f47a20');
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h43ubsr/)